# Min/max for itertools in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, brute-force

I've got this code:

```
import itertools
res = itertools.product('abc', repeat=3) 
for i in res: 
    print ''.join(i)
```

The problem is I don't know how I can also add a minimum and maximum to the word that's gonna be the output? So let's say I put in the letters `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` but I only want a minimum 1 letter and maximum 2 letter word: how would I do that? I've already searched on the internet, but couldn't find anything. It's meant to make a dictionary for brute-force.

Comment: What do you mean a minimum of 1 letter? Like you don't want 'aa'?

Answer (score 2):

Use itertools.permutations(). Then concatenate the results.

```
S = [x for x in permutations('abc',2)] + [ x for x in permutations('abc',1)]
```

Actually you could also use `products`. The only difference is that products removes duplicate results. But you won't have any duplicates when all the elements are distinct.

Comment: Considering the context (building a dictionary for a brute-force attack), it would make sense to allow duplicates, so using permutations would be better.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
import itertools
min_letters = 1
max_letters = 2
for num in range(min_letters, max_letters + 1):
    res = itertools.product('abc', repeat=num) 
    for i in res: 
        print ''.join(i)
```